# lstnewenvironment is not showing in lstlistoflistings

Tags: listings, sharelatex

I created two lstnewenvironment, one for Java, and one for pseudocode as following: (pseudocode not included here)

```
\documentclass{thesisPST}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstnewenvironment{java}[1][]
    {\lstset{
        language=Java,
        backgroundcolor=\color{light-backcolour},
        xleftmargin=0.7cm,
        frame=tlbr,
        framesep=0.2cm, 
        framerule=0pt,
        commentstyle=\color{codegray},
        keywordstyle=\color{codeblue},
        numberstyle=\tiny\color{codegray},
        stringstyle=\color{pgreen},
        basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
        breakatwhitespace=false,
        breaklines=true,
        captionpos=b,
        keepspaces=true,
        numbers=left,
        numbersep=5pt,
        showspaces=false,
        showstringspaces=false,
        showtabs=false,                  
        tabsize=2,
        mathescape=true,
        framexleftmargin=5mm,
        stepnumber=1,
        morekeywords={},
        deletekeywords={},
        identifierstyle=,
        moredelim=[il][\textcolor{codepurple}]{\$\$},
        moredelim=[is][\textcolor{codepurple}]{\%\%}{\%\%},
        moredelim=[il][\textcolor{codegold}]{@}
    }
}{}


\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

%after i created some code such as:
\begin{java}[caption=Die Methode doesAutomatExists ,label = c:doesAutomatExists]
    private boolean doesAutomatExists(String automatonName, List<ComponentAutomaton> automata){
        boolean res = true;
        for (ComponentAutomaton automaton:automata) {
            if (automaton.getAutomatonName().equals(automatonName)){ 
                res = false;
            }
        }
        return res;
    }
\end{java}


\backmatter
%Next i created a lstlistoflistings as following:
%but the list is empty
\phantomsection
\renewcommand\lstlistlistingname{Quellcodeverzeichnis}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Quellcodeverzeichnis} 
\lstlistoflistings
\end{document}
```

where did I go wronge?

Comment: It is impossible to debug disconnected fragments like that, please edit your question so the example is a single small document that shows the problem. Have you run latex enough times for the list to be complete?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I did.The lstlistoflistings ist there for already a month and I work almost everyday on the Doc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking close to the lstset, and the PDF, I saw that the codes does not have a caption.

By not having a caption, the lstlistinging wot appear in the thable of listings.

In order to solve this, I added two lines to the lstset under the lstnewenvironment.

```
1. `caption= #1`
2. captionpos=b
```

so I defined in which position the caption will be: 
e.g.

`\begin{java}[language=java,caption=Die Methode doesAutomatExists ,label = c:doesAutomatExists]`

and the caption was shown under the code, and added to the table.